# python X.509 parsing

Tags: python-3.x, cryptography, x509

Im about to parse base64 encoded certificates. For this purpose I used the `cryptography` package.

```
der = ssl.PEM_cert_to_DER_cert(base64Cert)
cert = x509.load_der_x509_certificate(der, default_backend())
```

With `cryptography.x509.Certificate` class I than have access to most of the certificate fields via `cert.[attribute]`. E.g.:

```
cert.version # prints 3
```

On the [website](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/x509/reference/#x-509-certificate-object), they state write, that the signature algorithm field can be extracted with

```
 cert.signature_algorithm_oid
```

This however, doesn't work for me. I get the error

```
AttributeError: '_Certificate' object has no attribute 'signature_algorithm_oid'
```

I already tried updating the cryptography package, but it doesn't solve the problem.

What would be the correct way to update the package?
Or is there a different way to get the signature algorithm field? For instance by manually parsing the der encoded file.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use `openssl asn1parse` or even the [Online JavaScript decoder](https://lapo.it/asn1js/) to find out the OID of the algorithm used to generate the signature.